# Cannot connect Oracle ldap server(OID) in a virtual machine through JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, virtual-machine, oid

I set up an Oracle with LDAP (OID) in an virtual machine, create a user named "qa1user" authenticated through LDAP server.

Check with SqlPlus in VM and successfully logon to Oracle:

```
sqlplus qa1user/xxxx
```

Then I port forwarding these ports as:
LDAP server port:  3060 --> 4060,
Oracle port: 1521 --> 11521

and could also logon to Oracle on the host where VM resides.

```
sqlplus qa1user/xxxx@localhost:11521/orcl
```

## Question:

I can not connect to LDAP through JDBC:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://127.0.0.1:4060/orcl,cn=OracleContext,dc=phl,dc=sap,dc=corp
```

and UserName is:

```
cn=qa1user,cn=Users,dc=phl,dc=sap,dc=corp
```

See the screen shot about OID configuration and errors.

[image: OID user configuration]

[image: Cannot connect outside VM]

Comment: The headings "Question 1" and "Question2" don't really make sense as you are not asking any questions in them. And if you were, I'd strongly recommend to restrict to **one** question per question. Ask a follow up question if you need, or a second question and linking between them for context. Otherwise, chances are your question will get voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, thanks for your suggestion, I delete Question 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I know the root cause. There's one listener running on my local machine, also listening on the port 1521, which counld not identify the database running in the VM. Shutdown it, and then everything is OK.